# Website Images dont get loaded, URL looks cryptic

Tags: google-chrome, url, dns

So on a website Iam working on some images dont get loaded.

The console says: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

and then a link like that:

```
http://s234127563.online.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/myimage.png
```

If I change the first part of the URL `http://s234127563.online.de/` to the actual URL `http://example.org/` the images get shown

Does anybody know what this problem is about? Maybe some DNS thing or something. I tried different browsers and to renew my ip address and flush dns etc. but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mismatch in your database. WordPress stores your base URL to generate permanent links etc.

1. Change the URL stored in WordPress. [There’s a page dedicated to that on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). Hardcoding the URL in wp-config is most reliable, but perhaps not most desired.
2. The URLs are saved in posts etc, so you may have to update those. [The Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin can do this for you.
3. Manually update non-default fields (theme options, custom fields, etc)

---

If none of the above works... are you using a CDN of some sort?

Comment: In the Backend at Settings -> General the Wordpress address and the Site address are the same as siteurl and home? Because these two are identical at the website. Or do I must check the database

Comment: @HansUllrich Try skipping to step 2 and 3. The URL is possibly somewhere in the database. By the way, are you using any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database. In the `wp_options` table there should be 2 rows, one called `siteurl` and the other one called `home`. Make sure both are set to be your domain name, so `http://example.org/`

Wordpress sets this URL at the start during installation, and if you for example had this URL set to something different before, in case of a migration to a different domain name or something else, it can differ from the domain name the website is currently being shown on.